# Importing a javascript library/module says it's undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, javascript-objects

I modularized my frontend build like so:
[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmcCd.png)

- Every component has its folder with its `.css` and `.js` (in the html
  folder).
- All the dependencies libraries go into `vendor.js`.
- All the `.js` components' files compile into `bundle.js`.

**- vendor.js dev-mode :**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import './assets/Swiper-3.3.1/dist/js/swiper.min';
import './assets/twentytwenty/js/jquery.event.move';
import './assets/twentytwenty/js/jquery.twentytwenty';

import './assets/PhotoSwipe/dist/photoswipe';
import './assets/PhotoSwipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default';
```

A component's `.js` example where I initialize the `photoswipe` library :

```
export default class Five {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Five');
        this.init_PhotoSwipe();
    }
    init_PhotoSwipe() {
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
        var items = [
            {
                src: 'https://placekitten.com/600/400',
                w: 600,
                h: 400
            },
            {
                src: 'https://placekitten.com/1200/900',
                w: 1200,
                h: 900
            }
        ];
        // define options (if needed)
        var options = {
            // optionName: 'option value'
            // for example:
            index: 0 // start at first slide
        };
        // Initializes and opens PhotoSwipe
        var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
    }
};

const five = new Five();
```

As you see in the code above I initialize the library with `new PhotoSwipe(...)`

The browser encounters an error and tells me that : **"Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoSwipe is not defined"**

**Note :** The `vendor.js` file is included before `bundle.js`, so it's strange why it can't see the `PhotoSwipe` variable.

The PhotoSwipe library code : https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/dist/photoswipe.js

**How can I initialize a new instance of the PhotoSwipe function?**

Answer (score 0):

PhotoSwipe is an AMD module, I couldn't import it as CommonJS.